# EmberJS: retrieving a property from a different endpoint

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building an Ember app that uses a Wordpress (WordPress REST API v2). Posts are returned on endpoint:

/posts and /posts/

However, I also want to retrieve the post category which is on endpoint:

/posts/categories

What's the best way to hit this endpoint and include the property on my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ember-api-actions](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions) addon. It seems to me, that is exactly what you looking for.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. 

I don't suppose you know if there is a similar plugin that will help me hit endpoints that are non-record oriented? Such as /options ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not entirely sure what does non-record oriented mean. If you mean something like JSON than you can use the built in JSONAPI adapter, and handle relationships with it.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me :)

I just mean, say, getting a value from an endpoint such as /options/twitter_url etc

I tried creating a model for it with a property of "twitterUrl" that used the ember-api-actions plugin to retrieve that value, but it said that it required an id to push it onto the store... which makes sense if it's something record-based (which has ids) but I'm not sure how I'd do it if it's something more static like "options"

Comment: Well I think you need to restructure your api endpoints a bit. For example:
GET /options // returns the list of options (and their value if you want)
GET /options/twitter_url // returns the value of the twitter_url option
POST /options/twitter_url // updates the value of twitter_url option
GET /options/another_option // returns the value of another_option
POST /options/another_option // updates the value of another_option
In this case the twitter_url will be your id :)